# Ограничение на память?

Tags: android, java

На телефоне свободный гиг оперативы. Захожу в приложение. Открываю многокартинные активити. После того, как приложение начинает занимать 60-70 мб оперативы, при попытке открыть ещё одну активити вылетает outofmemory error. Насколько я понимаю dalvik установил какое-то ограничение. Как снять?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это сделано специально. Что бы несколько приложений могло легко работать и не мешать друг-дружке. На разных версиях андроида это ограничение разное. В андроиде, начиная с третей версии можно попросить систему выделить побольше памяти, для этого в манифесте нужно указать ключик [largeHeap](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap). Но если Вашему приложению понадобился этот ключик, то это говорит о том, что скорее всего в приложении есть утечки и этим ключиком только оттяните падение.

На ранних версиях андроида выделялось 16мб, на 2.3 - 32 мб. На 4 андроиде по умолчанию выделяется 64мб. Но с включенным ключиком - до 256 (а на некоторых девайсах и до 300Мб).

Есть ещё один способ - поставить CyanogenMod - тогда в настройках можно будет изменять этот размер.

И есть ещё третий способ. Это использование jni. Память, которая выделена в нативной части, может занять практически всю доступную память.

Answer (score 0):

Если вылетает ваша программа, то можете попробовать увеличить [heap size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_largeHeap)