# Проблема при создании bitmap

Tags: android, java

В андроиде при создании bitmap выводит ошибку "create error". Это полный вывод ошибки. Прочитал на сайтах что в андроиде действует ограничение на создание bitmap. Максимальное разрешение это 4090 на 4090. При создании изображения от 3200*2000 выводит ошибку. 
Создуется изображение кодом:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(Width, Heigh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Сама ошибка тоже странная, поэтому даже не знаю в какую сторону думать.  Текст ошибки такой
 "create error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bitmap 3200*2000" - считаем:

1 px = (int value ARGB) 4 byte
3200*2000*4 = 25 600 000 byte ( ~25  + уже использованная память на другие нужды (MB heap) )

Про ограничения памяти отвечено здесь:

[Ограничение на память?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/230840/java-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C)

Вам нужно обрабатывать изображение не в HEAP памяти, а прямо на "диске" (возможно есть библиотеки для работы с большими изображениями - но тут я не Вам не помощник))))